Useful power of an induction motor driven at a lower speed
I'm somewhat confused in the physical/mechanical train from the motor to the end load.
I have a screw/nut arrangement to move a platform up and down (think about an elevator). Induction motor, pulley and then the screw system. At the moment it needs a 3kW motor to do it's job.
For reasons we want do change the screw to a multiple leaded one so that the effective pitch is greater (I mean, keeping the same ridge spacing a two leading screws in one turn moves double of the space). To keep the speed the same the idea is to use a VFD to drive the motor at half speed.
So there's the physics question: to move the load I have to expend some amount of Joules (gravity and mechanical losses) and, since the motion speed is the same, the power needed stays the same (the work time doesn't change). At the end of the day the work done is the same (ignoring differences in losses due to speed). Even if the screw turns slower the power needed is the same (because of the torque conversion changes).
However an induction motor gives constant torque. So if at 1500 rpm can give 3kW if I run it at 750 rpm the torque remain the same but the power is only 1.5kW, every motor curve says so. Even at zero rpm torque is more or less the same but the (mechanical) power is zero (because it's not actually turning).
Does this mean that I need a more powerful motor or have I missed some energy conservation step? (the obvious solution would be to use more motor poles to have a motor with 3kW at 750 rpm, of course)

Torque remains constant using the combination of frequency and voltage, up to the regular operating frequency of the motor.  So the power generated will be half the full speed power of the motor.  I don't think there is a good way to do this without changing the motor.  Similar to just buying a lower rpm motor, if you bought a 900 RPM motor compared to a 1800 rpm motor of the same power it needs to be made significantly larger (and more expensive).

Exactly what I tought. A 750rpm is two frames size bigger that the 1500rpm 4-poles (50Hz here). Just because there is more winding inside.
